# How to get list of installed apps via iTunes?

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore

I need to know what applications are installed or were installed on devices which are associated with iTunes account. I don't have access to the devices. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you have access to? The computer these devices sync to? Also there is no "iTunes account", are you talking about the App Store account used to by the apps?

Comment: Yes, I mean App Store account, I only have my account and password.
So I want to know which applications are installed on one of assoctiated devices with that account (these devices use my app store account and password to install applications and I don't have access to them)

Comment: Log in on https://appleid.apple.com and change the password. Problem solved :-)

Comment: But I don't need to change password, I want to see which applications my children install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see all purchases made through the iOS App Store within iTunes (on OSX or Windows):

- Start iTunes
- Log into the Store in the Store menu
- Show Account Details (in the Store menu as well)
- Shopping Statistics (don't know how it's called in the english version, it's the third block from the top)